# How to fix JSON result where headers is separated from values in PHP

Tags: php, json

I have a JSON result from a webservice, which is for some crazy reason, created like a table. See:

```
{
"headers": [
    "field_a",
    "field_b",
    "field_c"
],
"rows": [
    [
        "value 1",
        123.212,
        true
    ],
    [
        "value 2",
        542,
        false
    ],
    [
        "value 3",
        342,
        false
    ],
    [
        "value 4",
        5452,
        false
    ],
    [
        "value 5",
        32,
        true
    ]
],
"totalRows": 5
}
```

This sucks to work with, since I cant say $json->field_a, but instead I need to loop the "rows" in a foreach and access it as an array like $json => $obj {$obj[0]} to get the first value.

I'm trying to create a function like:

```
function fixOutput($jsonResponse){
$newResponse = array_combine(array_values($jsonResponse->headers), array_values($jsonResponse->rows));
}
```

But it give the warning:

> Warning:  array_combine(): Both parameters should have an equal number of elements

So, before I spend hours trying to find the correct solution, is there somebody how can help me, creating this method, the most memory-wise optimal way, since the JSON responses I'll get in production will have between 10 and 2000 rows.

Thanks in advance, guys :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function does not work because you are trying to combine the contents of the `$jsonResponse->rows` array with the `$jsonResponse->headers`, instead of combining each *element* of the `$jsonResponse->rows` array with the headers.

I would just use a plain old foreach loop.

```
$data = [];
$headers = $jsonResponse->headers;
$nrOfHeaders = count($headers);

foreach ($jsonResponse->rows as $row) {
    $newRow = [];
    for($i = 0; $i < $nrOfHeaders; $i++) {
        $newRow[$headers[$i]] = $row[$i];
    }
    $data[] = $newRow;
}
```

`data` now is an array containing associative arrays. You can trivially modify this example to use `stdClass` objects instead.

Comment: Works perfectly!! :D Thank you, Pete!